# How to delete a feature branch (or any branch) in Perforce?

Tags: perforce

I'm a Perforce newbie and I'm just starting to familiarize myself with Perforce's branching functionality. One thing I do not understand is how to delete a *feature* branch after I'm done working with it and the changes have been merged back into the mainline branch like you would do with a feature branch in Git.

Can you delete branches in perforce or do they remain permanently in Perforce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a task stream (which is what I'd recommend for a short-lived "feature branch" type stream), you probably want to "unload" it:

```
p4 unload -s //depot/task_stream
```

This is basically like deleting the stream with "p4 stream -d", except that you can get it back later if you want to.  As with "p4 stream -d", it also doesn't get rid of all of the files in the stream; the ones that you modified stay in the depot (so that you can follow the merge records back to the original submits if you want to), but all the unmodified files are unloaded (whereas with "stream -d" they're gone and there isn't any convenient record of what exact version they matched in the parent -- you can reconstruct it after the fact but it's harder).  Using "p4 reload" brings the task stream back to life.

If it's a normal stream and/or you want to get rid of it forever including the original changes in its depot path, you need to be an administrator (submitted changes in Perforce are generally considered Very Important and immutable unless you're an admin) and use the "obliterate" command, followed by deleting the stream spec:

```
p4 obliterate -y //depot/your_stream/...
p4 stream -d //depot/your_stream
```

Given your description I'd definitely recommend using task streams for features and "unloading" them when you're done.

If you're not using streams at all, the standard practice with branches is to either just leave them when you're done with them, or to reuse them (i.e. have an ongoing development branch that you merge into the mainline as you complete each feature).  You can obliterate a branch (as described above the in the stream example) but since this requires admin permissions it's not typical.

Comment: So task streams only work if you are using Streams in Perforce. We are not using Streams in our repo currently. I'll have to look into this. From this description it looks like I'll just have to leave my *feature* branch as is. This was a very useful answer.

Comment: @SamStafford: I would add that my team is currently generating about a hundred feature branch per month, and the more I use perforce, the more I am tempted to clear old feature branch just to keep my sanity when browsing repository or opening a revision graph. Even if there are downside I think this is the only way to keep the depot relatively clean and usable.

Comment: Using task streams is definitely the way to go since the unmodified files (the vast majority of them) are not visible except to clients of that task stream, and they go away when the stream is unloaded.